# How to express a browser window property as a specific type in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

In my Angular app's index.html, there is a script tag that includes a JavaScript file with 3rd party code that will attach a global property to the window object when the page loads.

I want to reference this property as a strongly-typed module within an Angular service.

I can get access to the property like so.

`const foo: any = (window as any).foo;`

However, the variable is of type "any" and I would like to express it as a specific type, "foo".

I have a "foo" typings file which I have placed in the following path within the Angular project.

`src/@types/foo/index.d.ts`

I modified the tsconfig.json to include the @types location.

```
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "src/@types"
  ],
```

The typings file exports a `foo` module like so:

```
declare module 'foo' { /* etc. */ }
```

It is at this point that I am stuck.  I must be thinking about it wrong, because I can't find any examples of this situation.

I tried using `/// <reference path="../../@types/foo/index.d.ts" />` to pull the type definition into service, but I am not sure what that buys me.

I tried creating a separate module that exports the foo module like this `export const foo = (window as any).foo;`, but Typescript doesn't detect the connection between it and the typings file.

I tried renaming the variable so that it would look like this `const baz: foo = (window as any).foo;`, but it doesn't work.

EDIT: 2019-12-05
Here's what I ultimately put in my Angular service.

```
import * as foons from 'foo'; //foo namespace
type WindowWithFoo = Window & { foo: typeof foons};
const foo = (window as any as WindowWithFoo).foo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast it twice to the correct type.

```
type WindowWithFoo = Window & { foo: SomeSpecificType};
(window as any as WindowWithFoo).foo
```

Comment: You would put it wherever you need it. In a service it would most likely make the most sense, as you would only want to do this once in a central place :)